# Is it possible to open and close a new activity with swipe gesture in Flutter?

Tags: android, android-activity, flutter, swipe

I want to open and close a new activity with Swipe gesture in a flutter in Android it can be done using libraries like Slidr but how can we achieve same in a flutter.

[Click link to youtube video to get the idea about how it is done in Android.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci5146VOyg4)

[Check the transition from one activity page to another](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1GiC.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a `PageView` widget instead since you just want to detect left and right swipes.

Example Code:

```
PageView(
  controller : PageController(initialPage: 1)
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(color: Colors.red),//  1st Page (Left)
    Container(color Colors.blue),//  Default Current Page (2nd Page)
    Container(color: Colors.green), // 3rd Page (Right)
  ],
)
```